# How to draw shapes on top of Silverlight multiscaleimage?

Tags: silverlight

There is a multiscale image with deepzoom image as a source.  Now I need to allow users to draw poligons and lines on top of the multiscalimage in such a way that the shapes will follow drag and zoom to scale accordingly.

I tried to add a canvas in addition to the multiscaleimage but can't figure out how to make them stick to each other on zoom or drags.

If you have done any user shape drawing on top of deepzoom image, please share your methods.

Thanks,
Val

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Silverlight 4 Puzzle demo?

http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/silverlight-4-html-puzzle-how-does-it-work/

You may be able to get some "inspiration" by inspecting this app.

Follow the link to download the source:
http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-4/html-puzzle/

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before. Not sure if this is the preferred/optimal way, but you can add layers to your root deepzoom layer. (sorry, i forget the proper terminology).

In my case i had 4 sub layers, some of which were used to render lines and shapes, others were used to render entire maps that were loaded from a URI.